# File pointers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, gdb

Very raw with C. I'm writing a program that takes files as it's arguments, but this is rather annoying for debugging (GDB). Rather than have to re-type the file list each time that I start off in GDB, I'd rather store the file names in an array and modify the program to read this array rather than the argv[] values.

I started out with

```
FILE*[5] inpFiles;
inpFiles[0] = &file1.txt;
```

but this is all wrong. I need to get some sort of reference to each of the input files so that I can get its memory address.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you not create a batch file to start your gdb session with the files listed there?

Comment: Maybe what you need is a local `.gdbinit`.

Comment: Do you want to store the array of files, or the array of file NAMES?  If the latter, you want something along the lines of the strangely deleted post by @laishiekai.  (I've done this before, in similar circumstances, and it's a perfectly legit "trick" when debugging.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a GDB command in `.gdbinit` so you don't need to modify your production code.
For example, add the following lines in your `~/.gdbinit` or `.gdbinit` in your working directory.

```
define do
    run file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
end
```

Then, in GDB, just type the command `do`, and GDB runs `run file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt` for you.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'll do, since I don't have to modify my program this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your input files, containing each of your files, by reading on the standard file stream 0.

so that you could do this:

```
 ./your_program < your_input_file
```

and in gdb,

```
  run/r < your_input_file
```

but if you want to keep your args method, you can also do this:

```
  ./your_program `cat your_input_file`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

An array of `FILE *` would be written:

```
FILE *inpFiles[5];
```

This can store the values returned from `fopen()` or a similar functions; it does not store file names.

You might store the file pointer into the structure that `&file1` represents, or you might create a new structure that stores the name and the opened file pointer (though you may need to specify a mode; presumably "r" or "rb" by default).

So, clarify to yourself what exactly you want to do.  You can create an array of file pointers, or an array of structures containing, amongst other things, a file pointer.  But you have to decide how you're going to use it and what the semantics are going to be.

---

This presumes that modifying the program is a better idea than using GDB better.  If you can learn to use the facilities of GDB more powerfully, then that's a better idea.

For example, can you make it easy to specify the files by using a metacharacter:

```
run debug?.txt
```

where your files are `debug0.txt`, `debug1.txt`, ...?

The other answers also suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. fopen() is mostly what I was missing to get a reference to the file.